# Wildyfly working when called on localhost but not fom another ip address

Tags: networking, tcp, wildfly

I have a Wildfly server running on port 8080.

When I try to access it from my pc using localhost:8080 or 'my_ip':8080 it shows the welcome page, however when I try to access it from another computer on the network, I get 404.

I tried pinging the server from the remote computer, and it passes fine.

When I run Wireshark on the computer where my Wildfly server is running to capture the traffic, I see TCP SYN packets from the computer that is trying to access it, but the response (SYN ACK) isn't sent back to the client.

I configured Wildfly to accept all incoming connections by setting

```
<interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
    </interface>
```

in interfaces in standalone.xml. I also tried with `<any-address/>`

**EDIT:**

I added an inbound rule in my firewall that allow incoming connections to port 8080 form any ip address. However, when I try to telnet to 8080 or nmap -p 8080 'my_ip', it still doesn't work.

The problem seems to be in the network rather then the Wildfy server itself since I tried tethering wifi from my phone, connecting my laptop that runs the Wildfly server on it and I can access Wildfly  page on 'my_ip':8080 from my phone

Answer (score 0):

try to telnet to 8080 port , if its open you will get replay .
if its blocking you need to stop firewall in your OS, if its working add correct rule for  that, and start firewall once again .

Comment: I added an inbound rule in my firewall that allow incoming connections to port 8080 form any ip address. However, when I try to telnet to 8080 or nmap -p 8080 'my_ip', it doesn't work.

Comment: its does not work means your firewall rule is not working correctly , for checking you just stop the PC firewall , and check once again . telnet host/ip port, also check it out that port listening or not with netstat –an ¦find /i “listening” //https://techtalk.gfi.com/scan-open-ports-in-windows-a-quick-guide/